# MS Word's grammar checker launches with VBA delete all line breaks in MS Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, spell-checking

I have this code in VBA which launches MS Word spelling and grammar checker after I exit  text box of a ms Access form.
After the check is run, and the text sent back to the form, all the line breaks of my text are gone. My data look like a single paragraph instead of having nice formatting.

This happen on the Access side as the .doc that I see just at the end of the spelling check still has the line breaks.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Description_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Call SpellIt(Description)
End Sub
Public Function SpellIt(ctrl As Control)
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document


    On Error GoTo SpellIt_Err

   Set wdApp = New Word.Application
   wdApp.Visible = True
   wdApp.Activate


      If Not IsNull(ctrl) Then
         Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
         wdApp.Selection.Text = ctrl
         wdApp.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
         If Len(wdApp.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
            ctrl = wdApp.Selection.Text
         Else
            wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            wdApp.Quit
            Set wdApp = Nothing
            Exit Function
         End If
         wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
      End If

   wdApp.Quit
   Set wdApp = Nothing

   MsgBox "Spelling and Grammar Check Complete.", vbInformation, "Microsoft Word Spelling And Grammar:"
   Exit Function

SpellIt_Err:
    Err.Clear
    ctrl.Undo
    MsgBox "We encountered an error in it's conversation with Microsoft Word regarding your comment." & vbCrLf & _
        "As a precaution, any changes made within the grammar and spelling dialog box have not been retained.", _
        vbCritical, "Spelling and Grammar Check NOT Complete:"
End Function
```

Comment: Hi.  I've run your code; the corrections I make in the Word document are never brought back into the textbox.  How can I make that happen?  Sometimes there are misspellings and I select Change, but the original text in the textbox is never overwritten, so I don't see the issue you wrote up.

Comment: It's working "good" as in you are not seeing the issue any more or the problem is happening as described now?

Comment: sorry for not being more clear. "Good" in the sense of the problem is happening as described now. So now the original text in the textbox get corrected by the spelling checker but this removes all the line breaks.

Comment: No worries.  This is a pretty cool idea.  I think I found your issue, too, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MS Word is using different linebreak characters than Access textbox controls.  You can revert the characters back to their original used in Access after spellcheck by replacing this line:

```
ctrl = wdApp.Selection.Text
```

with:

```
ctrl = Replace(wdApp.Selection.Text, vbCr, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: You did it! I even had a great surprise: as you say the line breaks weren't removed, I just had to run the check spelling again in my fields and they reappeared, without me having to add them again! This is so great! Thanks a lot!